# Post-Schema-Validation Infoset resources

Tags: xml, xsd

I have spent hours and hours searching for resources to learn about **Post-Schema-Validation Infoset of XML** but no luck. May I know where could I get **some tutorials or reference** regarding this topic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Post-Schema-Validation Infoset** (PSVI) expresses an XML document in terms of a data model consisting of the name, structure, and type information used during validation.

Definition of the [PSVI in XSD 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#key-psvi) :

> We refer to the augmented infoset which results from conformant processing as defined in this specification as the post-schema-validation infoset, or PSVI.

### Tutorials / Overviews:

- [Understanding XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468558.aspx)
- [Wikipedia's XML Schema entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29#Post-Schema-Validation_Infoset)

### References:

- XSD 1.0: [C.2 Contributions to the post-schema-validation infoset](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#PSVI_contributions)
- XSD 1.1: [B.2 Contributions to the post-schema-validation infoset](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#PSVI_contributions)
- Related: [XML Information Set (Second Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/)